# App crashes when checking array length

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I have been having problems with a particular part of my app for a while now and I thought it was fixed, but I've just noticed that it still seems to be crashing.

Basically, I have an array that stores preset names that users can use to save time. If a user uses a name that isn't a preset, then it is added to the list of presets. If they use a pre-existing preset, then it is moved to the top of the list. The list of presets is limited to 15 at a time.

The problem is that when I tap on the button that segues to the view controller that contains a table view of all of the presets, the app crashes.

I'm declaring the arrays like this:

```
var presetNamesMutable: NSMutableArray = ["Shopping", "Holiday", "Christmas", "Groceries", "Weekend Away", "Birthday", "Wedding", "Day Out", "Savings", "Party"]
var presetNames: NSArray = []
```

This is the code that is in the preset view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        presetNames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("presets") as NSArray
        presetNamesMutable = presetNames.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
        println(presetNamesMutable)

        while presetNamesMutable.count > 15 {
            presetNamesMutable.removeLastObject()
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(presetNamesMutable, forKey: "presets")
        }
}
```

This is the code in the view controller that deals with adding/moving names:

```
    if presetNamesMutable.containsObject(budgetName) == false && budgetName != "Budget" {
        presetNamesMutable.insertObject(budgetName, atIndex: 0)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(presetNamesMutable, forKey: "presets")
    } else if presetNamesMutable.containsObject(budgetName) == true && budgetName != "Budget" {
        var indexValue = presetNamesMutable.indexOfObject(budgetName)
        presetNamesMutable.removeObjectAtIndex(indexValue)
        presetNamesMutable.insertObject(budgetName, atIndex: 0)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(presetNamesMutable, forKey: "presets")
    }
```

The app crashes on:

```
        while presetNamesMutable.count > 15 {
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What's the actual error msg when it crashes? Does `println()`   display the array contents? Can you log `presetNamesMutable.count` instead? 

Not sure about your variable declarations. In Swift, the use of `var` vs. `let` takes care of mutability for you, so trying to use `var presetNames: NSArray = []` as an immutable array isn't correct. Explicitly downcasting a mutableCopy of that already-mutable array to NSMutableArray seems triply redundant.

Comment: I'm just getting `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`. println() doesn't seem to display the array contents. I tried commenting out the while loop but the app still crashes, so I guess it must be down to the mutableCopy. The reason I have a mutable copy is because using NSUserDefaults to store an array makes the array immutable, if I am correct?

Comment: @mc01 Surprisingly, the app will only crash if the user has never entered a name manually. So basically, if they try to use a preset name the first time they launch the app, then it will crash. But after the first use everything works fine...

Comment: If `println()` doesn't show anything, then it's crashing there & not on the while loop, meaning `presetNamesMutable` probably isn't what you expect. I'd suggest removing the `as NSArray` and `as NSMutableArray` downcasts & println each result. If they're `nil` and you use `as` to downcast, it unwraps the optional & expects a non-nil value. Could be that initial crash is due to a `nil` array? Also, whatever you store in NSUserDefaults should be immutable - that's sort of its purpose. You grab the stored contents & use a local mutable copy until it's time to save again anyway.

Comment: That sounds right. When I have some more time tomorrow I'll give that a try. I've posted a temporary fix that I'm using for now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix I changed my code to this:

```
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("presetsAvailable") == true {
        presetNames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("presets") as NSArray
        presetNamesMutable = presetNames.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
        println(presetNamesMutable.count)

        while presetNamesMutable.count > 15 {
            presetNamesMutable.removeLastObject()
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(presetNamesMutable, forKey: "presets")
        }
    }
```

Basically, when the user first used the app, it was crashing. So I have now made it so that the code that was crashing the app does not get executed until the user has used the app at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a swift version with a few println() statements to check for accuracy.  I limited the array to 10 values since that is the list provided and I didn't want to be too creative with holidays.  :-)   Paste this in a playground:

```
var presets = ["Shopping", "Holiday", "Christmas", "Groceries", "Weekend Away", "Birthday", "Wedding", "Day Out", "Savings", "Party"]

println(presets)

let name = "Shazam"

func isPreset() {
    if contains(presets, name) {
        println("presets contains \(name)")
    } else {
        presets.insert(name, atIndex: 0)
        println("added \(name) at index 0 of presets")
    }

    while presets.count > 10 {
        println("removed \(presets[presets.count-1]) from presets")
        presets.removeLast()
    }
}

isPreset()
println(presets)
```